# android studio 3.0 Beta 7 build tool 26.0.2 unable to create new project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

android studio 3.0 beta 7
Build tool 26.0.2
OS: Windows 10

unable to create a new project and throw an exception

Error Message: android-studio-ide-171.4010489-windows\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml

```
C:\Users\mahmoud\Downloads\android-studio-ide-171.4010489-windows\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
java.lang.AssertionError: C:\Users\mahmoud\Downloads\android-studio-ide-171.4010489-windows\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.DefaultRecipeExecutor.copyTemplateResource(DefaultRecipeExecutor.java:523)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.DefaultRecipeExecutor.copy(DefaultRecipeExecutor.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe$CopyInstruction.execute(Recipe.java:147)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.executeInstructions(Recipe.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.execute(Recipe.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$4.process(Template.java:568)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils.processFreemarkerTemplate(FreemarkerUtils.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.executeRecipeFile(Template.java:557)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$200(Template.java:73)
```

Comment: Try to reinstall, if that does not work use stable AS.

Answer (score 0):

its your internet connection problem with android studio.
Check your internet connection and restart Android Studio and try again to build and click on download API level 26 again.